# How to add NULL values in empty cells of csv while concatenating 2 csv files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, file, awk, sed

While appending 2 csv files with unequal number of rows , we need 'NULL' value in place of missing lines in csv.

in the below mentioned images

First file is having 5 rows while second is having 4 , so we need NULL in the last line of second CSV for all the columns. 3rd image is the expected final file.

[image: Sample first CSV]
[image: Sample first CSV]
[image: Expected final file after concatinating above 2 files]

we need command to add NULL in the missing cells

Comment: Please don't make destructive edits after you've received an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste` should help here along with `awk` to complete the file merge.

Firstly, let's determine the number of fields. Then, using `paste`, we merge both files line by line separated by ','. This output is then piped to `awk`. If it sees a line less than the expected field count, adds string "NULL" for the appropriate count. Otherwise, it is printed as is. Assuming files are file1.csv and file2.csv, here is the full code:

```
NUM_FIELDS=$(paste -d"," file1.csv file2.csv | head -1 | awk -F, '{print NF}')
paste -d"," file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, -v cnt="$NUM_FIELDS" 'NF < cnt {
printf "%s",$0; 
for (i=NF;i<cnt;i++) 
    printf "NULL,";
print "NULL";
next} 
{print}'
```

Here is the output:

```
ProductCc,SITE,BatchID,PROCESS_CATEGORY,DO actual,Runtime,Tank Volume,Open pipe
MK3,Biberach,15300289,BiologicsUpstream,60.62,14.396,12460.1,0
MK3,Biberach,15300289,BiologicsUpstream,59.33,14.403,12462.7,0
MK3,Biberach,15300289,BiologicsUpstream,60.68,14,41,12457.3,0
MK3,Biberach,15300289,BiologicsUpstream,59.99,14.417,12453.3,0
MK3,Biberach,15300289,BiologicsUpstream,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

p/s: In future, please include any sample data lines as text instead of images to simplify testing.

Comment: Thank you, we got the Null values as expected, but the second files contents are printing in new line , can you try to print in same line.